# How to synchronize JMeter Thread groups?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, synchronize

I read a lot of literature about JMeter but don't know How to synchronize JMeter Thread groups? 
I have 3 threads group: 

A thread group with 3 request (1,2,3)
B thread group with 3 request (4,5,6)
C thread group with SMTP Sampler

When I run project - request completed random. For example:
request 2 
request 4 
request 1 
request 3 
request 5 
request 6

But I want synchronize threads this 2 threads and after run 3rd threads with mail.
request 1
request 2
request 3
request 4
request 5
request 6
request send mail (SMTP Sampler)

how can I do it? can write simple example, please.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm tried with While Controller.
Wrote in second request: ${__setProperty(group2_done,TRUE,)}

and in 3rd request: ${__P(group1_done,)} && ${__P(group2_done,)

Comment: If you want the request to go in fixed sequence why are  you putting them in two/three at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the thread group one by one, Please select this option in your Test plan

[image]

Comment: In what version of JMeter is available this option ?

Comment: I have been using JMeter from its version 2.9. It is available. Not sure of the old versions.

Comment: hi, can you tell us what is the option coz I can see attached image ? thanx !